# What are the mechanical benefits of Recall Knowledge on enemies?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e

In the comments for [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160008/9552)  it was implied that Monster Hunter (Ranger feat 1) was good, because it lets you identify a monster as a free action.

Knowing a monster's *AC, saves, resistances* and *vulnerabilities* would indeed be great, but I could not find any such thing  at Recall Knowledge's description (CRB p239).

Is there any guideline on what I will learn, or is it completely up to the DM?

Comment: For the record, I was never trying to imply that it was "great", just useful. Still a good question to have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Game Mastering chapter, on page 506 of the Core Rulebook we get this information:

> **Creature Identification**
>
> A character who successfully identifies a creature learns one of its
>   best-known attributes—such as a troll’s regeneration (and the fact
>   that it can be stopped by acid or fire) or a manticore’s tail spikes.
>   On a critical success, the character also learns something subtler,
>   like a demon’s weakness or the trigger for one of the creature’s
>   reactions.

It is still left somewhat to GM decision what to share, but the intention is that you can learn one piece of information with one check, or two on a critical success. About what this "piece of information" is we get two other examples in the player section, on page 239:

> For example, Arcana might tell you about the magical defenses of a
>   golem, whereas Crafting could tell you about its sturdy resistance to
>   physical attacks.

These are really close to mechanical details, and I imagine this could mean a reveal of an exact numerical descriptor, such as AC or resistance, depending on play style. In most cases something like "You know it has a high Fortitude save" might suffice, as whether it has +20 or +25 might not change your decisions at all. The rules seem silent on how exact the information should be.

Also relevant is what we can read on repeated attempts to get more information, also on page 506:

> After a success, further uses of Recall Knowledge can yield more
>   information, but you should adjust the difficulty to be higher for
>   each attempt. Once a character has attempted an incredibly hard check
>   or failed a check, further attempts are fruitless—the character has
>   recalled everything they know about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly up to the GM, but it should be something useful; you spent actions (or bought an ability) and passed a check after all.

What exactly is "useful" is subjective. A common practice in Pathfinder 1st edition that many groups have taken with then to 2nd edition is that the player can ask questions, such as "what are its weaknesses", "what kind of energy resistances/immunities does it have", "what is its weakest save".

The GM is not obligated to allow such questions. If the GM deems that some other piece of information is more important, they could give that. For example, when meeting a weird bull creature, the GM may overrule the wizard's player who would like to know about energy weakness, because it's much more important to say that it's breath causes paralysis.

But when the GM doesn't have specific urgent information, using player questions is a good way to making sure the information is useful.